# Flask name logging file based on current date

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, logging

and im trying to write some logs into a log file, my goal is for each day create a log file which has the current date in it's name without deleting the old logs the code is below :

```
#define handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
handler  = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('myLogFile',when='midnight')
handler.suffix = '%Y_%m_%d.log'
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('werkzeug').addHandler(handler)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

The problem is the file created is only myLogFile without the suffix i've tried multiple things but it didn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: did you just try suffix as `%Y_%m_%d` ?

Comment: yes i only used that is there an alternative?

Comment: How did you verify that it's not working? You need to keep running the application for more than 24 hours.

Comment: the first file that was generated has only the name myLogFile without the extension.

Comment: But when i change the date in my computer and forward it to next day to test it generates with success but the first file is the problem it has no extension.

Comment: First will not have suffix if I'm correct.

Comment: yeah, is there any way around this to have the first one with the suffix.